# Looking for a word to sum up the process

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word which would sum up this process - you have a plain backyard, and you place there a table and chairs, build a playground for children and plant some flowers. And now comes the word: the backyard is ..... (facilitated?).

Comment: You could say "furnished", but you'd still likely have to say what it is furnished with.

Comment: We gave the back yard a makeover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of possiblities, but maybe "improved".

> We're going to improve our back yard with some decking and a play area.

Renovated (if you are restoring it to a good state)

> Our back yard was full of weeds, so we dug them all up and renovated it with new plants.

Revamped is a casual way of saying the same.